# Here.com V7.2 - Cannot create API Key

Tags: here-api

We are trying to create an account for access to the Routing V7.2 API.

We create a Project, and an App under that Project, and finally an API key under that App. We've made sure to link the Routing API under the project.

When we make a sample request in Postman

Request

```
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json
?apiKey={API_KEY}&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
```

Response

```
{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}
```

V8 is missing some key features for us (the ability to get miles by US state), so we need access to continue the project. When we tried this last year it was very simple, but the UI has changed.

Answer (score 1):

In March 2022, we launched the HERE platform for new self-serve users and the original developer portal stopped the registration, but it is still accessible for existing users. That is the reason why you saw the UI changes.

I assume that you created the current app through the HERE platform portal - https://platform.here.com/.

It is an expected result that the new apps on the HERE platform don't have the access to the Routing V7 (in maintenance mode).

To access Routing V7 API, you need to use the existing apps that were created in the developer portal - https://developer.here.com/.